# math box with notes

Tags: math-mode, environments, tcolorbox, notes

> I wanted to create a function for maths notes that makes this result but in an easy way, like the function `\underset{}{}` where you place between the brackets what you want to appear below the text, so this function I am asking for is one that box the equation and allows you to put something under (longer than a line) and something with in the right with the structure that I made.

Also if you see this could you comment any post related to math notes or margin notes, just for see examples of what to do. Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
              number within=chapter,
              list inside=myexercise
              ]{myexercise}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    title={{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\textbf{Ejercicio}~\thetcbcounter.~\textit{#1}\end{minipage}}},
    halign title=left,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
    overlay unbroken={\draw[black,double] (interior.north west)--(segmentation.west);},
    boxed title style={%
      colframe=white, 
      boxrule=0pt,
      colback=white,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift={-5pt}},
    underlay unbroken={\draw[help lines,step=3.8mm,black!20!white](interior.south west) grid (segmentation.east);},
    lower separated=false, 
    before lower = {\tcbsubtitle[colback=white, opacityback=0, colframe=black, opacityframe=0, boxrule=1pt, height=1cm,  width=2.55cm, valign=center]{\textbf{Solution:}}}
}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\underset{Hi}{\fbox{$\vec{m}_{total}=\displaystyle\int_{V'}\vec{M}(\vec{r'})d\tau'$}} $\longrightarrow\left|\substack{\\\text{ }\\d\tau'\text{debe ser lo suficientemente}\\\text{grande para que podamos}\\\text{considerar a }\vec{M}\text{ una función suave}\\\text{ }}\right.$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off topic ... the baselines for the text at the right are quite dreadfully uneven.  It would be much better looking if you put that text into a `parbox`; you will have to specify a width, but since you know how long the longest line should be, you can measure it and use that.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: @alvaritomendez just curious about the word `Hi` below the left block of your figure!

Comment: Because I didn't have anything under it, so to make a code of what I wanted to make in an easy way I put it there, but it is just for the example

Answer (score 2):

Here is my TikZ solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[nodes={minimum height=1.4cm}]
(0,0) node[draw] (L) {$\vec{m}_{total}=\displaystyle\int_{V'}\vec{M}(\vec{r'})d\tau'$}
(5.5,0) node[align=center] (R) {$d\tau'$ debe ser lo suficientemente\\grande para que podamos\\considerar a $\vec{M}$ una suave}
;
\draw[thick] (R.north west)--(R.south west);
\draw[->,thick] (L.east)+(0:.1)--+(0:1);
\path (L.south) node[below]{Hi};        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** This is `\mybox` - a `\newcommand` as requested.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% usage: \mybox{left}{right}{below}
\newcommand\mybox[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[nodes={minimum height=1.4cm}]
(0,0) node[draw] (L) {#1}
(5.5,0) node[align=center] (R) {#2}
;
\draw[thick] (R.north west)--(R.south west);
\draw[->,thick] (L.east)+(0:.1)--+(0:1);
\path (L.south) node[below]{#3};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\mybox{This is the left}{This is the right\\with some fomular}{and this is below}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\mybox{$\vec{m}_{total}=\displaystyle\int_{V'}\vec{M}(\vec{r'})d\tau'$}{$d\tau'$ debe ser lo suficientemente\\grande para que podamos\\considerar a $\vec{M}$ una suave}{Hi}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way of usin this as a \newcommand, where you have a bracket for what is inside the box, for what is under the box, and for what is in the right?

Comment: @alvaritomendez I added a new command. Is that what you want?

Comment: Great and awesome as always.

Comment: It's pretty good, but maybe my question is a bit confusing, I wanted to create a command (or maybe is an environment what I'm searching for) that recreates that with multiple lines for below and right text (so the width of the text could change), sorry if it wasn't clear. This is because is a format I want to use in more equations, also if a parameter is empty (like the right text bracket) it shouldn't appear all the structure. I know I'm asking for a lot, that's why your help is beeing really helpfull